# Are these two formulations equivalent?

Tags: set-theory, definition

Are the two following formulations of the Axiom of Pairing in ZFC equivalent?

$$ \forall a, \forall b, \exists d: ~ \forall c ~(a \in d \wedge b \in d \wedge \neg (c \in d))$$

$$ \forall a, \forall b, \exists d: \forall c~ (c \in d \leftrightarrow c = a \vee c = b ) $$

I find the first formulation to be more elegant, since it does not use equality which would have to be defined before.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you wrote it down correctly? It seems to say that for all $a,b$ there is an empty set containing them both.

Comment: You are right, I see. As it is written here, $c$ is not specified not to range over $a$ and $b$ too. That was the mistake. However, correcting it would make it less elegant in the first place.

Comment: Re "equality would have to be defined before". Usually, one uses FOL with equality to begin with. -- Nevertheless, if you also have the Axiom Schema of Comprehension, you could get away with $\forall a,\forall b,\exists c\colon A\in c\land b\in d$ and so "outsource" the details to a theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure you _can_ fix the first form. If you can "fix" it so you still have a question, please do so.

Comment: What I meant by the comment above is that one could specify $c$ to be a set for which $\neg (c = a \vee c = b)$. However, that would make it A LOT less elegant, which was the motivation for the question to begin with.

Comment: You should have an extra set of brackets around "$c=a\lor c=b$" in the second formulation, else it's ambiguous.